# JUnit (Selenium WebDriver) to open www.google.co.uk in Chrome Browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, junit4

I had tried to run below JUnit (Selenium WebDriver) test case to open Google in Chrome browser, but it is failing with error message as

> "The path to the ChromeDriver executable must be set by the
>   webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver."

As specified in that website, I downloaded ChromeDriver.exe but don't know, 
Which ***PATH*** should I place that? or 
How to set ChromeDriver path in webdriver.chrome.driver?

Please Advise.

My JUnit test case (changed the Firefox Driver to Chrome Driver):

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
public class Chrome_Open_Google {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    @Test
    public void Test_Google_Chrome() throws Exception {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have several options:

Either specify the folder (in which your chromedriver binary is) in your PATH system variable - [here's how](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Or give you application `webdriver.chrome.driver` as a system property by calling it with `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=the/path/to/it` parameter.

Or the same programatically: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your/path/to/it");`

Or this:

```
private static ChromeDriverService service;
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void createAndStartService() {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
            service.start();
}

@Before
public void createDriver() {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@AfterClass
public static void createAndStopService() {
    service.stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Petr. I had tried 1st, 3rd and 4th options, but it is still not working. And I couldn't get 2nd option. Sorry, I am new to Selenium. I have written JUnit code and trying to execute from eclipse.
After I set-up PATH as specified in 1st option, eclipse is not opening. It says JRE or JDK to be setup, which I believe JRE is already running in my system. 
For 3rd and 4th options, program shows error message in code. Eg, I placed chromedriver.exe in "C:/Selenium" folder, and if I specify in code as System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Selenium"); then it throws error message.

Comment: Um. Try the whole path including the name of the file? Otherwise, I'm pretty much clueless, too.

Comment: Well... Finally found it. Thanks for your help @Petr. I have searched in google with syntax, you have given System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",).

Correct way of writing is 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium//chromedriver.exe");

So actually we should code with "//" and not "/". That was the mistake I did. It finally worked. Thanq very much...

Answer (score 2):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your\path\to\it");
For Eg :

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\Selenium\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
```